# Lion Server - DNS crashing

Tags: dns, server.app

Every now and then (once per week?), my Mac Mini (2011, 8GB RAM i5) running Lion Server, stops the DNS server bringing my network to a grinding halt.  The only way I have found to get it to restart is by rebooting.

I've tried reading the logs to work out what is happening but cannot understand what they are saying.  Has anyone else seen this and if so, any thoughts on the fix?

Thanks

Comment: So you mean the mac mini can't resolve dns requests then ? I kind of have a similar problem